# Vlookup mapping in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, vlookup

I made is using Vlookup in Excel, Now I have do the same a webpage.

```
<div class="age">
    <label for="age" class="age"> Please Enter your age : </label>
    <input type="text" id="age" name="age" onkeypress='return isNumberKey(event)'>
</div>
<div class="bmi">
    <label for="bmi" class="bmi">Please enter your Body Mass Index value : </label>
    <input type="text" id="bmi" name="bmi" onkeypress='return isNumberKey(event)'>
</div>
<div class="afc">
    <label for="afc" class="afc">Please enter your antral follicle count (afc) value : </label>
    <input type="text" id="afc" name="afc" onkeypress='return isNumberKey(event)'>
</div>
<div class="amh">
    <label for="amh" class="amh">Please Enter your Anti-Müllerian hormone (amh) level : </label>
    <input type="text" id="amh" name="amh" onkeypress='return isNumberKey(event)'>
</div>
```

There are 6 arrays

```
var values = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25,26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100];
var age =    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
var bmi  =   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
var afc =    [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
var amh10 =  [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
var d2fsh =  [2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 4, 4, 3, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
```

I have these spans where user can get the result after performing some internal calculations.

```
 <div>
        Final Score: <span id="result"> </span>
        Percentage: <span id="percentage"> </span>
        result: <span id="result"> </span>
    </div>
```

For each input of the values of different fields, the input value should me mapped to the corresponding value from the array

for example. If the age input is 45, The value of 45th index of age array should be returned

I have attached the excel file for reference: [Reference Excel](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FHkeb6h-hHyI0xL40ImR1ucJ0dQ1ADNq/view?usp=sharing)

How should I go about it. looked up lot of examples, but none of them deal in multiple arrays/inputs from users.

Comment: Just an idea, concat your arrays to one big array and then get the 45 indexs value? You can use https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat

Answer (score 0):

It would be great if you could explain what exactly is the issue without requiring us to analyze your excel.

To return the n-th element from an array you can simply do `array[n]`

To find index of an element with value X you can call `array.indexOf(X)`